# concrete examples of finite morphisms $f:X \to Y$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to learn algebraic geometry, and I don't seem to have a large list of concrete examples. What are some concrete examples of finite morphisms of projective (irreducible) varieties $f:X \to \mathbb{P}^2$? Also, what are some concrete examples of non-normal surfaces? Any references for algebraic geometry with a lot of examples?

Comment: Usually, textbooks on algebraic geometry do not have so many examples, examples come from your experience by reading various books, articles or solving exercises,

Comment: Your question contains three distinct questions, two of which are quite specific and one quite general. You might get better responses by asking these as separate questions. My answer below only addresses the question about finite morphisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me offer a counterpoint to the answer of Alexey Do, to try to show that natural projective geometric constructions give examples of finite morphisms.

I will use a very general fact (referenced on the Wikipedia page [Finite Morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_morphism)) that a morphism is finite if and only if it is proper and quasi-finite (the latter meaning that its fibres are finite). Since morphisms between projective varieties are always proper, this means that you are just looking for examples of morphisms with finite fibres.

A commonly-occurring example is the following. Let $C \subset \mathbb P^2$ be an irreducible plane curve, and let $p \in \mathbb P^2$ be a point not lying on $C$. Then projection away from $p$ gives a morphism $C \rightarrow \mathbb P^1$. The fibres of this morphism are of the form $C \cap L$ where $L$ is a line in $\mathbb P^2$ passing through $p$. Since $C$ doesn't contain $p$, no such $L$ is a component of $C$, and so $C \cap L$ must be finite. Hence our morphism $C \rightarrow \mathbb P^1$ is a finite morphism. This kind of morphism can be used, for example, to prove the degree-genus formula for plane curves.

If you want an example of a finite morphism $f \colon X \rightarrow \mathbb P^2$ you can just use the same construction, *mutatis mutandis*: that is, start with a surface $X \subset \mathbb P^3$ and project away from a point $p$ not on $X$. Indeed, by working a little harder you can prove that *any* projective variety $X$ of dimension $n$ admits a finite morphism $f \colon X \rightarrow \mathbb P^n$. This is a form of the so-called *Noether normalisation lemma*.